# How to implent a simple search function in angular on a Table and to show the matching rows only

Tags: angular, typescript, search

I have search option on Table, I want to show the searched content on the page that the user wants. How can I attain that by  writing a corresponding function in code of typescript.

Comment: What have you tried already? We aren't here to write code for you. See the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *ngFor to create the rows in your table and use a pipe

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | filterPipe: searchToken">
```

Add a search field

```
<input placeholder="Type to filter" [(ngModel)]="searchToken"/>
```

In the component add the variable searchToken

```
searchToken: string;
```

Add a custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchToken: string) {


        if (searchToken == null)
            searchToken = "";


        searchToken = searchToken.toLowerCase();

        return items.filter(elem => elem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchToken) > -1);
    }

}
```

Finally don't forget to put the pipe into the declarations in ngModule:

```
declarations: [ App, FilterPipe ]
```