# How should I filter links in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project in which data is being loaded from server. There are some links with `.jpg` which are being fetched. I don't want them. So I tried this way to filter out links with `.jpg` format file:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$|async" class="result">
    <div class="link">
        <p filterLink(item.link)>{{item.link}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in `.ts` file of the component -

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

 fileFormat: string;

}

filterLink(link) {
    this.fileFormat = link.filter(fileLink => !fileLink.includes(".jpg"));
    return this.fileFormat;

}
```

But the code does not working. Is there something I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: What exactly is `filterLink(item.link)` supposed to be as an attribute? When you say *"does not working"*, could you expand with a [mcve]?

Comment: Use a custom pipe for filtering inside of your *ngFor [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

Comment: @jonrsharpe `item.link` are the links which are being loaded from servers. What I thought, to pass the values by creating a function `filterLink()` and check each url. :)

Comment: Do you want something `*ngIf="filterLink(item.link)"` then? In that case `filterLink` should return true or false whether it should be shown. The way you're applying it now makes no sense syntactically.

Comment: @Ludwig it would be great if you can provide me an answer. I'm learning this tech stack. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hm. Okay. I'll try it.

Comment: Just have a look at this answer which is somehow similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315437/how-to-implent-a-simple-search-function-in-angular-on-a-table-and-to-show-the-ma/44315797#44315797

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! Your solution works perfectly! :)

Comment: @Harshit I would prefer filtering the invalid / not wanted links in the service as part of the http request. you can easily use `filter` method from `rxjs`. To me it seems like this isn't UI logic this is business logic and should belong to the service or -even better- it should already be filtered on the server if possible